# Is there a way to nest a cell reference into another cell identifier in a function?

Tags: google-sheets

Let's say I have Cell A1 with an integer of 3000 in it that changes daily based on a CSV feed. Now I have a list of 10000 rows in column B with different variables that I need to count.

Now I have a function of =countif(B:B, "example"). However, that counts all of row B. Is there a way to do count only the number of rows that match the integer in A1? For example I tried  =countif(B1:B(A1), "example")

But it obviously didn't work and im struggling to find a similar example on google

Comment: something like this `=countif(indirect("B1:B" & A1), "example")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sergey has left a suggestion in the comments section below the original post. I will suggest a couple of other approaches and tell why I recommend them:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(B:B,"example",ROW(B:B),"<="&A1))`

-or-

`=COUNTA(FILTER(B:B,B:B="example",ROW(B:B)<=A1))`

`INDIRECT` is a perfectly fine function. However, it does have a drawback. That is, it does not adjust if you insert, delete or move rows or columns. For instance, if you reference `INDIRECT("B2:B"&A1)` and then insert a column such that Col B becomes Col C, `INDIRECT` will still reference Col B. If your sheet is very simple and you only have one `INDIRECT` call, you can find the problem and fix the formula fairly simply. But imagine a sheet full of `INDIRECT` calls, or even one that has just a handful staggered around the sheet. For this reason, where possible, I save `INDIRECT` for times when I know that layout changes will not affect it or as a last resort.